# Adding umbraco:item fileds in templates with uSiteBuilder for Umbraco

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, umbraco

I have successfully tried uSiteBuilder templates tutorial but on them, no umbraco:item are used. When I tried those, they did not work.
The code I am using is standard:

```
<umbraco:Item field="ShowGlobalNavigation" recursive="true" runat="server"></umbraco:Item>
```

But it does not resolve to the appropriate field.
I know it is because the 'umbraco' control space is not defined but I have not seen it anywhere in the uSiteBuilder documentation.

I am using Visual Studio 2010, Umbraco 6.1.6 and uSiteBuilder API6 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simply a matter of casing for the field attributte.

uSiteBuilder automatically lowers the first letter of the property name.